# Function select.select get hangs with python sockets and Tkinter

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I have been trying to fix this error for 3 days, I can't solve it until now.
I made a simple server that can handels multiple clients and all works fine. Now I am trying to go with the code and put it with some UI (Using Tkinter) and I came with no success.

The code below is hangs on the select.select function.

I am guessing that the problem is in the client code, this is the client code:

```
class OtherFrame(Tk.Toplevel, HandleScreens.HandleScreens):
def __init__(self):
    print 'Classsd'
    Tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
    self.root = self
    self.root.geometry('800x450+350+150')
    self.root["bg"] = "#3498db"
    self.root.title('My Project')
    self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.doSomething)

    client_socket = socket.socket()

    port = 3548

    host = '0.0.0.0'

    client_socket.connect((host, port))



    print 'Connected to the server'

    while True:

        sockets_list = [sys.stdin, client_socket]

        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(sockets_list, [], [])

        for curr_sock in rlist:
            if curr_sock == client_socket:
                data = curr_sock.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    print '\nDisconnected from server'
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    pass

            else:
                client_data = ''
                client_socket.send(client_data)
```

This code is just hangs. It's do nothing. I hope that someone have an idea what I need to change.

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Its because that while loop you have never ends. If I were you, I would put everything currently in the while loop in a new definition, then at the end of the definition code write `self.root.after(10, <new def name>)`. This will stop your code from blocking tkinter and therefore the entire program.